# Why is Brahma referred as Viranchi in Scriptures?

Tags: scripture, brahma, sanskrit, terminology, etymology

In some scriptures [Brahma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma) is referred as Viranchi (विरञ्चि):

Whenever I see sun raising in early morning, following mantra automatically pops out from my mind/month:

> नमः सवित्रे जगदेकचक्षुषे । जगत्प्रसूती स्थिति नाश हेतवे 
>  त्रयीमयाय त्रिगुणात्म धारिणे । **विरञ्चि** नारायण शङ्करात्मने॥
>
> Salutations to the Sun God, the Eye of the Universe, the Cause of Creation, Maintenance and Destruction of the Universe, the three Gunas, taking form as **Brahma**, Vishnu and Shiva.

Above mantra is from Surya Mandalashtaka.

Another example from memorized Narmadashtakam:

> **विरिञ्चि** विष्णुशंकरस्वकीयधामवर्मदे त्वदीयपादपङ्कजं नमामि देवि नर्मदे ॥
>
> The presence of **Brahma**, Vishnu and Shankara in Your Holy Dhama (i.e. River body) provides a Protective Shield (of Blessings to the Devotees), O Devi Narmada, I Bow down to Your Lotus Feet, Please give me Your Refuge.

As you've seen in above examples, Brahma is referred **Viranchi (विरञ्चि)**. So, I want to know why is Brahma referred as Viranchi in Scriptures?

Comment: In different kalpas the Brahmas are known by different names,,Virinchi,Padmabhu,Swayambhu,Parameshti etc are those names..They are mentioned in the [Skanda Purana](http://www.astrojyoti.com/skandapurana-13.htm)

Comment: @Rickross You can post answer with Skanda Purana referance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Virañci means "he who creates."

Following are the various names of Brahmā from the [Puranic Encyclopedia](https://archive.org/stream/puranicencyclopa00maniuoft#page/155/mode/1up).

> In Amarakośa, the following names are given to Brahmā.
>
> Brahmātmabhūḥ surajyeṣṭhaḥ 
>   Parameṣṭhi pitāmahaḥ | 
>   Hiraṇyagarbho lokeśāḥ 
>   Svayaṁbhūścaturānanaḥ ||
>
> Dhātābjayonir druhiṇo 
>   **Virañciḥ** kamalāsanaḥ | 
>   Sraṣṭā prajāpatir vedhā 
>   Vidhata viśvasrṭvidhiḥ ||
>
> Nābhijanmāṇḍajaḥ pūrvo 
>   nidhanaḥ kamalodbhavaḥ | 
>   Sadānando rajomūrtiḥ 
>   Sattyako haṁsavāhanaḥ ||
>
> - Brahmā — he who increases.
> - Ātmabhū — born of his own accord or born of the Supreme Spirit.
> - Surajyeṣṭha — he who came into being before all the suras (gods).
> - Parameṣṭhin — he who dwells in the world of truth or Parama.
> - Pitāmaha — grandfather of the manes such as Aryamā and others.
> - Hiraṇyagarbha — having the golden egg (mundane egg) in womb.
> - Lokeśa — the god of the worlds.
> - Svayaṁbhū — who is born of himself.
> - Caturānana — who has four faces.
> - Dhātā — who holds or bears everything.
> - Abjayoni — born of lotus, (abja)
> - Druhiṇa — who hurts asuras.
> - **Virañci** — **he who creates**.
> - Kamalāsana — who sits on lotus.
> - Sṛṣṭa — he who creates.
> - Prajāpati — Pati of prajas (Lord of progeny).
> - Vedhā — he who creates.
> - Vidhātā — he who does.
> - Viśvasṛt — who creates the world.
> - Vidhi — he who does or decides or judges.
> - Nābhijanmā — born from the nave of Visnu.
> - Aṇḍaja — born from the egg.
> - Haṁsavāhanaḥ — who has swan as his conveyance.

Monier-Williams dictionary just [says](https://archive.org/stream/1872sanskriten00moniuoft#page/934/mode/1up) it's another name of Brahmā:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From [Sanskrit Dictionary](http://sanskritdictionary.com/vira%C3%B1ci/214873/1):

> **virañci विरञ्चि**
>
> Definition: m. idem or m.  idem or 'm. (perhaps fr. [rac](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=rac&iencoding=&lang=)-). Name of [brahmā](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=brahm%C4%81&iencoding=&lang=)-   ' '

So, विरञ्चि (Viranchi) *perhaps* comes from Sanskrit word [रच्](http://sanskritdictionary.com/rac/187903/1) (rach) which means to generate/make/produce/create.

Now, as Brahma is the creator of world/universe, Viranchi refers to Brahma.

<sub>Note: This is not exact or final answer I think as it is based on "विरञ्चि (Viranchi) *perhaps* comes from Sanskrit word रच् (rach) . Answer with better/scriptural reference/source will be appreciated.</sub>

Comment: A good place to look for an etymology would be Yaska's Nirukta.