# What are the different names of Brahma as per scriptures?

Tags: scripture, brahma, name

What are the different names of Brahma as per scriptures? Are there 28 names of Brahma?

Comment: According to Amarakosha, Brahma has 29 names. But I cannot use Amarakosha to answer this since its a Buddhist text.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Amarakosha is considered as an authority even by Sanskrit scholars and Historians and wrote commentaries on it. Even Adi Shankara regarded it as a great book.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma So can we use it in answering this question?

Comment: Yes, @Sarvabhouma, Amarakosha is considered as the root of all as it originated from Veda (I listen from a Pundit, he also own that book)

Comment: अजः पद्मजः पितामहः  ब्रह्मा विभुः विरिञ्चिः धाता विधाता विधिः कर्त्ता प्रजापतिः हिरण्यभूः पद्मभूः हिरण्यगर्भ  these are basic names or names especially referred to Brahma. Then other names are composites describing aspects of Brahma, like जगत्कर्त्ता सुरेश पद्मासन पङ्कजासन कमलासन लोकेश लोकरचयिता जगत्कारी et cetera. In fact, पङ्कजासन can also be called as a basic name, because when we say Pankajaasana it usually refers to Brahma, same for JagatKartaa and alike.

Comment: Visit [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16273/277) to the question [Why is Brahma referred as Viranchi in Scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16270/277), which lists 23 names of Brahma from AmaraKosha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lord Brahma has following names as per **Kurma Purana** (English translation [source 1](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/kurma_purana/creation.html), [source 2](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/kurma_purana/brahma_vishnu_and_shiva.html)):

- **Hiranyagarbha**: The word garbha means womb and since Brahma originated from inside a golden (hiranya) egg, he is known as Hiranyagarbha.

  > [image]
- **Adideva**: He appeared in the very beginning (Adi) hence AdiDeva.
- **Aja**: He had no birth (janana) in the real sense of the term. He is therefore also referred to as Aja (without birth).
- **Prajapati**: Brahma was to be the lord (pati) of all the subjects who were going to be born (praja). Thus, Brahma acquired the name of Prajapati.

  > [image]
- **Brahma**
- **Parmeshvara**

> [image]

- **Svayambhu / Swayambhu**: It is also true that he created (bhuva) himself (svayam). It  is because of this that Brahma is known as Svayambhu.
- **Padmayoni**: Brahma appeared inside the lotus (not right at the beginning, at the time of the original creation (where Brahma was born inside a golden egg) but later in the beginning of a Kalpa (which is just a day of Brahma)). Since padma means lotus and yoni means place of birth, Brahma is also known as Padmayoni.
- **Dhata**
- **Vidhata**
- **PraPitamaha**

> [image]

- **Pratham Purush**
- **Kapil**
- **Vedmurati**
- **Pradhan Pusrush** / **Purush Hansa**

> [image]

---

Lord Brahma has following names as per **Skanda Purana** (English translation [source](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/skanda_purana/different_names_of_somnath.html)):

- **Shatanand**
- **Virinchi**
- **Padmabhu**
- **Parmeshthi**
- **Surajyeshtha**
- **Hemagarbha**

Comment: "As per the XYZ Purana the names are these" - I don't think that suffices. You need to do a lil bit of more work than that :D

Comment: @Rickross hope, it's okay now? :)

Comment: Yes now that u've added the sources it must be ok.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16273/12304