# What is the history of Brahma's birth?

Tags: brahma

I am looking for details about Brahma's birth, his parents etc. I have never heard about it. can any one explain real detail about it,.

Comment: Have you seen Padmanabha swamy , a Vishnu's form from which Brahma is born of his navel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [What are the different names of Brahma as per scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/what-are-the-different-names-of-brahma-as-per-scriptures/27812#27812) post, Lord Brahma is known as Hiranyagarbha, Aja and Svayambhu:

- Because the word garbha means womb and since Brahma originated from inside a golden (hiranya) egg, he is known as **Hiranyagarbha**.
- He had no birth (janana) in the real sense of the term. He is therefore also referred to as **Aja** (without birth).
- It is also true that he created (bhuva) himself (svayam), It is because of this that Brahma is known as **Svayambhu**.

So, in the very beginning Brahma originated from the cosmic egg.

---

As per **chapter 9 of Kurma Purana**,

At the end of a Kalpa (which is just a day of Brahma), lord Vishnu entered the body of Brahma and

> 22. He became surprised on seeing this entire set of the three worlds, including Devas, Asuras and human beings in the abdomen of that god ( Brahma ) .
> 23. Thereafter Vishnu, the deity with the Lord of serpents, Sesha as his abode, came out of his mouth and spoke to Pitamaha (god Brahma, the grand-sire of the world).
> 24. O excellent Purusha, in this manner you too enter my eternal abdomen and see all these wonderful worlds.

But when, Lord Brahma entered in Lord Vishnu's abdomen, Lord Vishnu closed all openings. Later, Lord Brahma found a lotus emerging from Vishnu's navel and came out from this lotus and asked Lord Vishnu why he closed all the openings.

> [Lord Vishnu to Brahma:]
>
> 34. It was only for fun. It was not with a desire to harass you. Who would wish to trouble the grandfather, the Lord of Devas?
> 35. O Brahma, you are not harassed. In every respect you are worthy of being honoured. O auspicious one, please forgive me the offence committed against you (i.e. if I have offended you). [v.l. whatever has been done by me to you is int he interest of your progeny.]
> 36. O Brahma, for this very same reason be a son unto me. O deity in the form of the universe, be famous by the name **Padmayoni** (having lotus as the source of origin) for the sake of my love.
> 37. Then that Lord [Brahma] conferred the boon to the crowned one (i.e. Vishnu).

The same chapter explains that Brahma also asked a boon from Shiva to born as his son. And later on Shiva was born as Brahma's son Rudra.

---

It's out of a boon that Hiranyagarbha Brahma appeared as Vishnu's son i.e Padmayoni Brahma. This is same as how Shiva appeared as Brahma's son i.e. Rudra. Due to these boons, it's believed that Vishnu's son is Brahma and Brahma's son is Rudra.

But as explained in [What is the Life span of Hindu gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23190/what-is-the-life-span-of-hindu-gods/23603#23603) post, Brahma, and even Vasudeva and Sankara are created by **Brahman (the Ultimate Reality)**. He alone devours them again, and their remanifestation also take place. Brahman (the Ultimate Reality) can be related with AdiNarayana, Mahākāla, SadaShiva and AdiShakti as per different sects' belief.

Answer (score 1):

Brahma was born from the lotus that emanated from the navel of Lord Vishnu. So, Lord Vishnu is the father of Brahma and naturally, Goddess Lakshmi, wife of Vishnu, is the mother of Brahma. The details of birth of Brahma can be found in Bhagavatha purana [Canto 3, Chapter 8.](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/8/)

Comment: there is a catch...Lord Brahma was emerged from Lord Vishnu's navel when he was almost completed half of his age..in the beginning he emerged from golden egg hence known as Hriyangarbha or Svyambhu..