# Does Ramayana say that Brahma was born from the belly lotus of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, brahma, lotus

It seems unlikely because he is equated to Parabrahman in some places in the Ramayana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Valmiki Ramayan: Uttar Kanda: Chapter 10](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-10) mentions Lord Brahma as lotus born:

> Thus addressed by the Devas, **Brahma, the Lotus born God** told them; "O Devas, I have found a solution. Do thouh all leave without any worry." Saying this unto the celestials, the great God thought of the goddess Sarasvati Vagdevata().

> Addressing the goddess **the lotus born god** said; "Do thou speedily repair to where Kumbhakarna is doing his penaces. Do thou enter his body and influence his tounge Hearing this she immediatly repaied to the spot where Kumbhakarna was doing his penaces.

Though in [Valmiki Ramayana: Balakanda: Sarga 70](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=1&field_sarga_value=70&field_sloka_value=20), he is mentioned as  manifested from the unmanifest Brahman directly:

> From the unmanifest was born the eternal, the constant, the imperishable Brahma. To him was born Marichi and to Marichi, Kasyapa.

---

This is the case with other scriptures too. For example, in Kurma Purana, Lord Brahma is mentioned as Swayambhu (self born), Aja, Hrinyagarbha in one place but at another place as Padmayoni.

The reason for this is also given in Kurma Purana, it says that **in the beginning Lord Brahma was self born but in one Kalpa he entered into Lord Vishnu's stomach and came out from his belly lotus**. This is discussed in [What is the history of Brahma's birth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36499/what-is-the-history-of-brahmas-birth/36502#36502) post.

Comment: Interesting - shows the interpolated nature of balakanda and uttarakanda beyond doubt.  How Gods undergo demotion of status (that too from the status of supreme brahman) totally flabbergasts me about Hinduism.@yds

Comment: So "lotus born" was just an avatara of Brahma who is supreme brahman.  This has been made into comedy theater by later scripture. Brahma is no more lotus born than Krishna is Yashodha born" or "Devaki-born".  these are just attributes..

Comment: That's not even an avtara.. u can relate Brahma's lotus-born name with Usanas's name Shukra.. though they were not born actually in that way but that became too famous even replacing their actual birth story...

Comment: So the ubiquitous images of Vishnu lying on his back, a lotus springing from his belly and brahma sitting demurely on it are adding glory to Vishnu but take nothing away from Brahma being supreme brahman? @YDS