# how come the same scripture declares a deity to be Brahman and also created by another deity and subordinate

Tags: untagged

Ramayana says Brahma is Brahman , but is also lotus-born.

Mahabharata says Siva/Rudra is Brahman and created Vishnu and Brahma, but also says many many times that he is Brahma's son.

Are these Taratamya assertions in scripture fluid and are meant to be taken metaphorically?

Comment: It's easy to understand. i'll say for one case: Rudra came from eyebrow region (Ajña region; he's Ajña swarupa Parameswara) of Brahma.. he came *from* Brahmā and it doesn't mean Brahmā is cause. Same as how Rāma was born to Supraja and it doesn't make Supraja superior or Rāma inferior. when you see philosophically, everything makes sense.

Comment: How do you interpret Prajapati's son who was given many of Siva's names to free him from Sin?  it is a supreme talking point for sects that reject Siva @The Destroyer

Comment: Where does Ramayana call Brahma as Parabrahman?

Comment: take a look at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45411/does-ramayana-say-that-brahma-was-born-from-the-belly-lotus-of-vishnu @Adiyarkku

Comment: Aiyyo oh this lineage chapter is too shady. It is repeated in Ayodhya Kanda without proper context. Funny part is this chapter doesn’t match with Ikshvaku vamsha of Puranas.

Comment: @SK didn't get..which son? you mean Rudra beheading Brahma's head?

Comment: the story in shatapatha brahmana in which a son is born to brahma who cries that he is not free of sin.  Brahma then gives names that are now associated with Siva - rudra,bhava etc,  @The Destroyer .

Comment: @SK shastras explain tattva as stories..Veda Nirukta gives many meanings for Rudra..that meaning is also present in Nirukta..