# Does the present Brahma have a name (apart from Brahma or Prajapati or Hiranyagarbha)?

Tags: brahma

This question assumes Brahma is not Brahman but is a post that gets filled by different entities over time.  Do we know the names of previous Brahmas, like we know the names of many Manus?

EDIT:

[What are the different names of Brahma as per scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24922/12489)

is different - it asks for names of the same Brahma - not different Brahmas as this question asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Skanda Purāņa, Prabhās khanda, Prabhas kshetra Mahatmaya, chap 7, from verse 10 onwards it is said as follows:-

> adhunā vaiṣṇavīṃ raudrīṃ yātrāṃ sarvārthasaṃyutām |
> vaktumarhasi cāsmākaṃ purāṇārthaviśārada|| 10 ||

> 10. Six Brahmās have passed away. The present Prajāpati who is well-known as **Śatānanda** is the seventh one, O goddess.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626794.html

Comment: Fair is fair, although I would have preferred a source other than Skanda purana :- ) @krsnadasa

Comment: The Sanskrit doesn’t match with the English. Seems to be talking of a tirtha yatra.

Comment: Someone edited it, thus the sanskrit got misplaced